# HTML SEO : Why my page identified as two different pages

Tags: seo, unique, title

I use sites that check out my website for SEO And I get the following message: 
    "his page title is not unique. Assign unique, descriptive TITLE tags and headings to every     page."
    accessbar.co.il
    accessbar.co.il/index.aspx
But it should be the same page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

Your home page can be pulled up using two different URLs:

- accessbar.co.il/
- accessbar.co.il/index.aspx

They may be the same page to you, but to search engines they are two separate URLs and thus considered two separate pages. You should do one or more of the following:

- do a 301 redirect from `accessbar.co.il/index.aspx` to `accessbar.co.il/`
- put a canonical URL on `accessbar.co.il/index.aspx` pointing to `accessbar.co.il/`